# Tensorflow C++, how to convert tensorflow::Output to Tensor

Tags: c++, tensorflow

Tensorflow C++, how to convert type `tensorflow::Output` to type `Tensor`, without using the `Run()` function.

After `Conv2D()`, I want to use the function of `FusedBatchNorm()`.

```
auto Conv2DOut = Conv2D(...);

auto BatchNorm = FusedBatchNorm(..., Conv2DOut, ...);
```

But the function `FusedBatchNorm()`'s input parameter x's type is `Tensor`, not `tensorflow::Output`.

So, I need convert `Conv2DOut` to `Tensor`. If this can not be done, it maybe a bug with TensorFlow C++.

Comment: I don't understand. FusedBatchNorm takes a bunch of tensorflow::Inputs, for which Output can be used. Can you clarify? Maybe you means to do `auto conv2dout = Conv2D(...).output;`?

Comment: @EdwardMa i have a same problem. i wanna convert tensorflow::output to a regular tensor but couldn't find any doc  or solution. did you solve your problem ?